# Dart converting Future function to a generic Future function

Tags: dart

I'm trying to convert one of my functions that takes something from Firebase and converts it into a list of models. I noticed I keep using this logic so maybe the best way to refactor it was to use generics.

**My original code:**

```dart
Future<List<Guideline>> getList ({DatabaseReference query}) async {
  DataSnapshot snap =  await query.once();
  Map<dynamic, dynamic> map = snap.value;
  _myList = new List<MyModel>();
  map.forEach((key, value) {
    _myList.add(MyModel.fromJson(key: key, snapshot: value));
  });
  return _myList;
}
```

I tried to use this similar logic to create a generic version of it but I got an error while trying to make it work and I couldn't find a similar problem while searching here so I decided to ask out.

```dart
Future<List<T>> getList<T>({DatabaseReference query}) async {
  DataSnapshot snap =  await query.once();
  //dynamic generates an error: The name 'dynamic' isn't a type so it can't be used as a type argument.
  Map<dynamic, dynamic> json = snap.value; 

  return list;
}
```

If I hadn't gotten the error above I would continue my code as how I did with my first function except that `fromJson` would be a callback function so I could pass its implementation.

Comment: I really don't understand your first example. Where does the guidelines and _guidelines variables comes from and what type does this have? Perhaps you could make a small complete example showing the context of this method.

Comment: If `dynamic` is not a type, either you are not importing `dart:core` (very unlikely) or are using `dynamic` in a place where it occurs as the name of a declaration, like `var dynamic = 1;` or something. Try looking for that.

Comment: I've just tested your code on https://dartpad.dartlang.org/ and it works without problems. Maybe you need to check your environment

Comment: I found the cause...it was my bad. I had another line of code I forgot to comment out: `T dynamic Function(Object) fromJson;` I was trying to get another thing to work from another SO question. Sorry bout that. So that line is supposed to be after the snap.value line, and it caused the error.